# Force line height in gridview

Tags: html, css, gridview

I have a GridView with template fields and labels in its item template. The height is set to be 12px through CssClass. (line-height=12px;height=12px). Everything works the way that I expect.

Once I give visibility to a TextBox, than the line height increases by approximately 1px per row, even though I reduce the height of the Textbox to a hypothetical 5px.

```
<asp:templatefield HeaderText="Result" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Result") %>' id="LabelResult" CssClass="NarrowGrid" visible="false"/>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextBoxResult" Height="5px"  Width="25px" Visible="true" CssClass="NarrowGrid"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:templatefield>
```

How can I achieve/force 12px to be the line height in both cases?

Comment: Post the relevant CSS code.

Comment: .NarrowGrid  {height: 12px; line-height:12px}

Comment: Post it in your question not in a comment. Anyway, your problem doesn't seem to be in the code you've posted so far. Perhaps the space at the end of the line is wrapping to below. Can you post the generated HTML?

Answer (score 0):

```
input{
   height: 12px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

hoped it helped

Comment: No, it did not :(